# Getting rid of softmax saturation in DeepMNIST-like net for colour-images classification in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, softmax

I have a dataset for classification which is composed of a training of size 8000x(32x32x3 images) and of a test of size 2000x(same size images).
I am doing a very simple task of distinguishing vehicules and background. I am using the cross_entropy as a cost function.

The net I am using is almost the same as the one used in [DeepMNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#second-convolutional-layer) except the first filter has size 3x... instead of 1x... because it is a colour  image and the output has size two because there are only two classes : vehicules or not vehicules. 
Seeing the results of this relatively straight forward task has led me to ask myself several interrogations :

-First if I do not use a large enough batch size (>200) I get stuck almost every time at accuracy 62% (in a local optima) over the two sets which is not sufficient for my need

-Secondly whenever I use the right optimizer Adam with the right batch size and learning rate I go up to 92% however the outputs are always very disturbingly good like [0.999999999 0.000000000001].

This should not happen as the task is difficult.
Therefore when I go fully convolutional to create a heatmap I got 1.000001 almost everywhere due to the saturation.
What am I doing wrong ? Do you think whitening would solve the problem ? Batch normalization ? Something else ? What am I facing ?

Comment: Whitening the data and adding batch normalisation only worsen the result ! The saturation is there and the accuracy is not good enough ! Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a sign of overfitting. If you train on small dataset long enough with a large enough model, eventually your confidences get saturated to 0's and 1's. Hence, same techniques that prevent overfitting (regularization penalties, dropout, early stopping, data augmentation) will help there.

My first step for a tiny dataset like this, would be to augment the dataset with noise corrupted examples. IE, for your example I would add 800k noise corrupted examples with original labels, and train on those.

Comment: Great answer thanks !!! I suspected overfitting a lot however as I got the same kind of error on train and test set I discarded that hypothesis. it must be that my test set looks too much like the train set and thus it generalizes well  ! 
I did not want to go into data augmentation just yet but I guess my training is too small for this kind of network. 
I did appreciate greatly your estimation of the number of noisy examples to create. Would you be so kind as being more precise on where in the net you would place your dropouts ?

Comment: Hm, that's suspicious actually. If you don't get close to 100% accuracy you shouldn't get much saturation. That's because giving wrong prediction with confidence 100% while training is going to send your parameters off into infinity in the opposite direction. Deep MNIST already has dropout after fc1, you could try to add another after after fc2

Comment: Yeah that is one of the reason I thought it was not overfitting ! It seemed strange to get saturation at 60% accuracy or so !( which I now get with batch renormalisation whitening and dropout on fc1!)
What are the most probable causes that could lead to this behaviour ? Exploding gradients ?Do you think there could be something wrong with my implementation ?
I will add it to fc2 thanks ! I guess it is smart to only apply dropouts on the fully connected part of the net as filters cannot really overfitt data as they always work kind of the same way.

Comment: I would do some sanity checks on your implementation. If your network predicts almost 100% confidence but training error is 92%, then the gradient on 8% of the examples is going to be huge, and destabilize your training. Unless Adam normalizing weights also become huge, but that seems like a long shot. Also, the batch-size -- you get more efficient learning (less epochs needed, hence less overfitting) with smaller batch size. You shouldn't be getting stuck at 60% because you pick smaller batch size

Comment: Thanks for your insights gonna have a busy week-end !

Comment: Even without adding noisy examples as it so happens adding heavy l2 regularisations on fully connected layers got completely rid of my problem !!! But I still want to add noise to produce more training examples. I was wondering which kind of noise and of which variance to add. Knowing that I go from 0-255 uint 8 images which I whiten afterwards. I suppose I add before whitening but do I add noise of like 0.01 of the variance of the sample image what is the rule ?

Comment: The common strategy is to add enough noise so that it's visible, but where you can still visually recognize the class

Comment: Thanks I will go with that strategy you have been really helpful thks a lot !